# how to pass the value of str1 to another page named "onclicked.php"?

Tags: php

[here's my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGZkc.png)

how can i pass the value of str1 to another page named "onclicked.php"

Comment: Read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply pass it as a GET parameter

```
var str1 = str.innerText;
window.location = "onclicked.php?str1="+str1;
```